# LibreOffice custom list of languages (for document, selection, paragraph)

Tags: language, libreoffice

(This was also [posted on the ask.libreoffice site](https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/custom-list-of-languages-for-document-selection-paragraph/17531), which is not a stackexchange site, so don't hurry closing or down-voting for that reason. But if you do, for whatever reason, please mention that reason too and I'll try fix it.)

I want to switch quickly between languages for spelling corrector as I use documents in multiple languages. When I already have a such document, with different paragraphs already set for a specific language, all the languages involved appear in the list of options for selecting the corrector language. But if this setting is not yet done for the different paragraphs, the list usually contains only the default language.

[image]

Sometimes the program is trying to guess the language but fails (shows Portuguese instead of French for example).

I know how to select a certain language if it is not listed in the menu or the taskbar list by selecting 'More' and going to a window titled 'Character' where languages can be also set:

[image]
<sub>(source: [libreoffice.org](https://ask.libreoffice.org/upfiles/1456830284650808.png))</sub>

but I find that very complicated for every selection.

**Is it possible to always have three or four selected languages in the menu list that opens** when clicking the language taskbar (or when right-clicking an underlined word) - first image above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution (as indicated in [this](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/65384/custom-list-of-languages-for-document-selection-paragraph/?answer=65412#post-id-65412) answer) is to add a style for each language and save the styles in one template that can be then set as the default.

By choosing the style, spelling automatically changes to the selected language. You can choose styles with F11

[image]

Select custom styles at the bottom drop-down menu.

Right click in that window and select 'New'.

Set font and language and other options, especially the name of the style, then click **Apply**.

[image]

[image]

Use F11 to see styles and double click one of them to select the one you want.

But there is a problem: **styles are saved for each document, opening a new document you will not see any styles or you will just see the default one** under Custom styles when pressing F11.

The [solution to this is](https://superuser.com/a/297394/162573):

In the document where you have created all your styles delete all text and go to  'File - Templates - Save as template'.

[image]

Then, make that template default **for all new documents**:

File/Templates/Organize (may appear as File/Templates/Manage) then click on the template and set as Default Template

[image]

Now **in a new document** all your styles will be available under Custom styles when you press F11.

[image]

**Old documents have their own template and are not affected by this change**. To get a new template in an older document:

Press F11, then select a drop-down menu with the option 'Load styles',

[image]

then select your template that was saved before.  In this way the styles in that template will be added to the ones already present, if any. To keep a certain list of styles (a template) for that document, save the document after any template changes.

**All languages added as styles in a template will appear in the language selection menu in the documents that use that template**. For the styles above:

[image]

[image]