# How to switch quickly between corrector languages in LibreOffice?

Tags: language, libreoffice

If a document has already multiple languages setting, these might appear in the taskbar language selection list or the right-click menu 'Set language...'. But when that setting for multiple languages is not yet in place specifying different corrector languages is a bit tedious, as one has to select 'More' and then go to a window titled 'Character', where there is also hidden a drop-down menu for languages:

[image]

Is there a way to specify certain languages and change/access/cycle them easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To control the list of entries in the language-selection menus (like taskbar language option or in the right-click menu to set language)**:

go to Menu "Tools" > "Language" > "For all text" > "More" or Menu "Tools" > Options" > "Language Settings" > Language and set different languages for User interface, Locale and Default.

[image]

More [here](https://superuser.com/a/1047264/162573). Those **three languages** will then appear always in the language-selection menus.

[image]

---

**To set a shortcut for each language (of a selection, paragraph etc.)**:

initially answered [here](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/6642/shortcut-for-changing-language/?answer=24895#post-id-24895).

- Enable recording macros.

3.5.x
Menu Tools > Options > LibreOffice > General
☑ Enable experimental (unstable) features.

4.0.x 
Menu Tools → Options → LibreOffice → Advanced
Optional (unstable) options
☑ Enable macro recording

More [here](http://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/2335/record-marco/).

- **Tools > Macros > Record macro**
- Select text, then go to **Tools > Language**, and chose the way you want the language to be applied with that specific macro:  **For selection, For paragraph or For all text** - and chose the language. Then click '**Stop recording**' in the floating window that appeared. An window should open to save the macro with a specific name. Do the same for different languages.
- To assign shortcuts to each macro go to **Tools > Customize > Keyboard**, select both the shortcut keys and the macro (under **Functions > Category > Libreoffice macros** - etc, as seen in the image below) and click **modify**.

[image]

Comment: Not all shortcuts work in fact. In 7.2 in Linux `Ctrl+<some number>` doesn't work for all numbers. In that case `Ctrl+Alt+1...etc` worked.